# How to access audio stream in real time when using Tokbox

Tags: ios, swift, voip, opentok, tokbox

I'm building a voice-only IOS (swift) app and [Tokbox](https://tokbox.com/) is my VoIP provider.

My app is simple: user1 is talking to user2. However, I would like to get access to the audio stream in real-time. I'm ok with both options: 1. The audio stream goes to my piece of code then I stream it back to Tokbox 2. The audio stream is forked to Tokbox and to my code in parallel.

The only way I was able to put my hand on the audio stream is by using their [archiving](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/) capabilities, but that is too late (only after the session ends)

Any ideas? or maybe other providers that give me that option?

Comment: Provide the code where you have started your Audio Unit

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 can be done using the external/custom audio driver, take look at this example on how to use/implement it https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/tree/master/Custom-Audio-Driver